# Propagate values in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a simple script that uses CAPDEPTH like a count variable and calls some tests for each value.

```
#!/bin/bash
# SCRIPT ONE
CAPDEPTH=1
...
while [ $CAPDEPTH -lt 11 ];
do
    echo "cap depth - $CAPDEPTH"
    make test-all-basics
    let CAPDEPTH=CAPDEPTH+1
done
```

And in line

```
eval "make test-all-basics"
```

It will do multiple calls to another shell script which I also want to make dependent on value of CAPDEPTH. Here are couple of lines from that script.

```
# SCRIPT TWO
...
R_binary="${R_HOME}/bin/exec${R_ARCH}/R"
capture_arg="--tracedir $(CAPDEPTH)"
...
```

My question is how to get the value of CAPDETH propagated from SCRIPT ONE to SCRIPT TWO. Is that even possible?
I've tried export of the variable CAPDEPTH in both scripts, but does not seems to work.

Comment: Why the `eval`? Why not just `make test-all-basics` directly?

Comment: @kojiro Good point. Originally, names of tests were passed by a file, but I understand now, that eval is redundant in this case. Is that connected with a question though?

Comment: If you mark a name for export it will remain marked in all child processes unless a child process unmarks it. A name marked for export will retain the value set in a parent process through its children unless a child process changes it. So if your name doesn't have the value you expect, or is unset, look for what's unexporting or changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
# SCRIPT ONE
CAPDEPTH=1
...
while [ $CAPDEPTH -lt 11 ]; do
    echo "cap depth - $CAPDEPTH"
    export CAPDEPTH # Makes it so that any child process inherits the variable CAPDEPTH and anything it contains.   
    make test-all-basics
    let CAPDEPTH++ # Increments CAPDEPTH by +1
done


# SCRIPT TWO
...
R_binary="${R_HOME}/bin/exec${R_ARCH}/R"
capture_arg="--tracedir $CAPDEPTH"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside script one use,

```
export CADEPTH=....
let CADEPTH=...
echo $CADEPTH
```

and inside script two, do:

```
source script1
```

and then,

```
echo $CADEPTH
```

Comment: Thing is that script 1 calls script 2. So if I source in source script1 in script2 it looks like I'm getting an infinite loop

Comment: All you need is to `export` the variable in script 1 -- no other changes required.